# How to guarantee that some code is executed before a program closes?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I know using a `with` statement will guarantee an open file is closed, but how can I guarantee, for instance, that the program's active data gets written to the file and saved before the program terminates?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module. For example, you can do the following:

```
def cleanup():
    #do cleanup here


# In main somewhere:
atexit.register(cleanup)
```

This will execute the cleanup function when the program terminates.

Comment: WOW that's good to know about. Although I wish I could get a better understanding of what does and does not qualify for "The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called." Like, what counts as "a signal not handled by Python", or a "Python fatal internal error"?

Comment: SIGSEG, SIGKILL (`kill -9`), SIGBUS, etc are things that no program can continue running after.

Comment: It means that if, for example, you kill the process manually from an external utility (like the process list on your os), it is not called. In other words, `atexit` only works if the program has been asked to quit *'nicely'* rather than forcibly terminated.

Comment: yes. for example many programs lock themselves in a loop and never check for the `ctrl+c` signal, and thus pressing `ctrl+c` doesn't cause them to stop. In fact on a pure command-line interface, `ctrl+c` would be the ONLY way to quit a program 'nicely', since there's no file-menu or 'x' button on a GUI window.